# Put SSL certificate and https on a passenger server (sharetribe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ssl, content-management-system, sharetribe

I currently have a problem with putting my SSL certificate on my VPS :
Here's what I use :
- sharetribe opensource for my website
- passenger for the server

I launch the server on port 80 for putting it online, and actually the port 443 is used by a Apache default page (I normally use nginx)

How can I secure my sharetribe server ?

Sorry if i'm not really precise, but i'm a beginner ! :/
I'm open to any question or answer!